# Phalcon - Lazy loading is not working in Models for some strange reason

Tags: php, activerecord, phalcon, volt

I am new to phalcon and coming from more of Symfony background, i just need to know how define optional relationship between foreign keys in phalcon models.

i.e 
Users table PK is user_id, and Users May have(Optional) related record in Photos table to have photo with primary key photo_id and linked by 'user_id'.

So in my falcon models i need to load Users with the photos if there is a one.

In user model

```
 public function initialize()
{
    $this->hasMany(
        "photo_id",
        "Photo",
        "photo_id",
        array(
            'alias' => 'photos'
        )
    );
}
```

IN photo model i write it as

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->belongTo(
        "user_id",
        "User",
        "user_id",
        array(
            'alias' => 'user'
        )
    );
}
```

In volt to access to it via

```
{{user.photo.photo_id}}
```

But this gives me error

```
Undefined property: Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple::$photo_id
```

Any idea ?

Strangely if do this code in the controller it works and get me the photo models but not when i try to access it with lazy loading /

```
$users = User::find(array(
"limit" => 10)
);
echo "There are ", count($users), "\n";
foreach($users as $user){
$photos = Photo::find(array(
"user_id=:user_id:",
"limit" => 10,
"bind" => array("user_id" => $user->user_id)
)
);
if($photos->count()==0){
echo "<br />";
echo "No photo found for user".$user->user_id;
}
foreach($photos as $photo){
echo '<br />';
echo "User ->".$photo->user_id." Photo -> ".$photo->photo_id;
}
}
```

When i try to do it with lazy loading like this

```
foreach($users as $user){
    //echo $user->photos->photo_id;
    foreach($user->photos as $photo){
        echo '<br />';
        echo "User ->".$photo->user_id."  Photo -> ".$photo->photo_id;
    }
 }
```

I get the error:

> Undefined property: Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple::$photo_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue seems to be caused by i am having two database connections like below which is causing some problems in the DI set.

```
return new \Phalcon\Config(array(
    'database'    => array(
        'adapter'  => 'Mysql',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'dbname'   => 'db_main',
        'name'   => 'db_main',
    ),
```

needs to keep only one database with name "dbname";

thats all i did to fix

Answer (score 2):

When using `$this->hasMany()` relation you should iterate through all records:

```
{% for userPhoto in user.photo %}
    {{ userPhoto.photo_id }}
{% else %}
    User has no photos
{% endfor %}
```

Also check the models names (it must be the same as model class name):

```
$this->hasMany(
    "users_id",
    "Photos",
    "photo_id",
    array(
        "alias" => "photo"
    )
);
```

Also adding an singular alias for `hasMany` can be confusing (the previous version of answer assumed one-to-one relation) so I would name this alias `"photos"` not `"photo"`.

On the other hand if `User` can have only one `Photo` then use `$this->hasOne()`.

Example:

```
        $this->hasOne(
            'photo_id',
            'Photos',
            'id',
            array('alias' => 'photo')
        );
```

Database structure:

```
Users: id, photo_id // other like name, email
Photos: id // other, like url, type, etc
```

Then you could use `$this->photo->photo_id` when there is associated data in database.

The simplest solution then would be:

```
{% if user.photo %}{{ user.photo.photo_id }}{% endif %}
```

Second, the error: When using `hasMany` relation Phalcon gives you result of searching multple related objects (so it is `Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple` which is default return of 'search multiple objects' like `Model::find()`).

Comment: nope, i dont knw if this is correct db design or not, users can have multiple photos, so its one to many and relationship is photos has user_id but in users we dont have photo_id because its optional link to users to have photos.. do you get me ?

Comment: If so look at the last example. This will work if you have hasMany() relation. Also I'll update one thing in a sec.

Comment: nope foreach ddint work, for somereaosn it doenst load the photos with the user model, not sure where the problem is

Comment: So double check: column names (it must be proper order as defined in docs - which I've found once confusing and had to check which parameter was for which model), models names also matters (ie namespaces must be provided).

Comment: Please check "Photo" vs "Photos" when defining relations.

Comment: no luck i think it may be the my service layer modle with repositories to access model is what is causing the problem,

Comment: do i have to define FK relationships in the mysql db to get this working ? at the moment i dont have FK constrainsts in the db ...

Comment: No. It should work without FK I think or as far as I remember it worked that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62717/discussion-between-mahen3d-and-jodator).